# Connecting to SQL Server database from a Visual Studio 2010 debugging session in a virtual machine

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, database, silverlight

I installed VS2010 on a VMware Workstation virtual machine. The database I use for debugging is on an IIS server that is connected to the host PC. When the Silverlight Application that is running in the virtual machine tries to connect to the database the following error is shown: "Unable to connect to database. Please Check your network connection."

From a browser in the virtual machine I can run the installed server application an access the database.

Is there a limitation with the localhost:55982/Default.aspx, the wcf client and the server authentication to access the database?

Answer (score 0):

I believe your problem would be better addressed in the VMWare Support forums. You see depending on the type of configuration of your network card in your VM, it could be configured to do Bridged, Host-only, or Network Address Translation (NAT), the network would behave very differently.  In your case the configuration you need is NAT as it would allow you to consume resources from your local network but not provide them.

See reference http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1006480

Hope that helps!